# Вопрос по использованию цикла для функции preg_replace

Tags: массивы, php, циклы

Есть код:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $noreplacearr = array(
        1 => "[b]",
        2 => "[/b]",
        3 => "[i]",
        4 => "[/i]",
        5 => "[ins]",
        6 => "[/ins]",
        7 => "[url=",
        8 => "[/url]"
    );
    $replacearr   = array(
        1 => "<b>",
        2 => "</b>",
        3 => "<i>",
        4 => "</i>",
        5 => "<ins>",
        6 => "</ins>",
        7 => "<a href=",
        8 => "</a>"
    );
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++) {
        echo "$replacearr[$i]";
        $text = preg_replace("$noreplacearr[$i]", "$replacearr[$i]", $row[1]);
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

> `Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: No ending matching delimiter ']' found in Z:\home\localhost\www\inc\mod\2\21.php on line 27`

Строка 27 и есть строка с `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $noreplacearr = array("[b]", "[/b]", "[i]", "[/i]", "[ins]", "[/ins]", "[url=", "[/url]");
  $replacearr = array("<b>", "</b>", "<i>", "</i>", "<ins>", "</ins>", "<a href=", "</a>");
  $text .= str_replace($noreplacearr, $replacearr, $row[1]);
}
echo $text;
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо!!!!!!!!!